# Save prawn pdf in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I am using prawn gem to generate PDF and i have this link in my app show page `show.html.slim`
`= link_to "PDF", post_path(@post, :format => 'pdf'), :target => "_blank`

My post controller show method

```
def show
@post = post.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.pdf { render :layout => false}
end
```

end

My `show.pdf.prawn` page has:

```
font("app/assets/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf") do

table [["Title \n #{@post.title}"], [''], ['Summary']], cell_style: {  size: 14, bold: :true }, row_colors: ['F0F0F0'], column_widths: [540] do
row(0).align = :center
row(0).size = 16
row(0).background_color = '93AAD9'
self.header = true

row(2).align = :center
row(2).background_color = 'DEB8A5'

end
```

......

I want the pdf to be saved automatically to `app/assets/pdf folder` in my app when i go to show page.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Add prawn save after `respond_to` block:

```
filename = File.join(Rails.root, "app/assets/pdf_folder", "x.pdf")
send_file filename, :filename => "x.pdf", :type => "application/pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use `render_to_string` for a minimal modifications to your architecture:

```
# controller code
format.pdf do
  filename = Rails.root + "app/assets/posts/#{params[:id].to_i}.pdf"
  unless File.exists?(filename)
    File.write(filename, render_to_string)
  end

  send_file filename, :filename => "post_#{params[:id].to_i}.pdf", :type => "application/pdf"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Following proposed in prawn-rails documentation (works also for prawn_plus).

```
#controller
format.pdf do
  headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"charts-#{Time.now.to_i}.pdf\""
end
```